# Apostol Analysis Problem 6.5 Prove that $f(1)>1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $f$ be a real function defined over $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)>0$, $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x$ and if $x \leq y$ then $f(x) \leq f(y)$. Let $A=\{x \ : \ f(x)>x\}$ Prove that $\sup A \in A$ and that $f(1)>1$

I have already proved that $\sup A \in A$ but I don't know how to prove that $f(1)>1$. I was trying to prove that $1= \sup A$. Since $a \in (0,1]$ then $a \leq 1$, so all I need to do is to prove that $1 \leq a$. Could someone help me with a hint?

Comment: The idea is to use the technique of the proof of the Heine-Borel Theorem (that $[0,1]$ is a connected space).  Let $B=\{x\in[0,1]:\forall y\in [0,x]\,(f(y)>y)\}.$  (i).  Show $\sup B\in B$.  (ii) If $\sup B<1$ and if $t>0$ is sufficiently small, there exist $y.y$' with $0\le  (\sup B)-t<y<\sup B<y'<(\sup B)+t\le 1$ such that $f(y)>y>f(y')$, a contradction (as $f$ is increasing). So $\sup B=1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=\sup A$ but $f(a)\le 1$, then $f(a)>a$ implies $f(f(a))>f(a)$, hence $f(a)\in A$. For any $x\in A$, we have $x\le a<f(a)$ so $f(a)$ is both contained in $A$ and is a strict upper bound of $A$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $f(a)>1$ is forced.

$f(a)>a$ implies $f(f(a))\ge f(a)$ since $f$ is weakly increasing, but $f(f(a))\neq f(a)$ holds because $f(x)\neq x$ always. Then $f(f(a))>f(a)$ is true.

Comment: Why does $f(a)>a$ imply $f(f(a))>f(a)$?

Comment: @FShrike (+) You have $f(f(a))>f(a)$ beacuse $f(x)\neq x$ and $f(a)>a.$ The function $f$ does not need to be strictly increasing. For example $f(x)\equiv 2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc True. I wrote the proof $f(f(a))\ge f(a)$ and $f(f(a))\neq f(a)\implies f(f(a))>f(a)$ but replaced it with the incorrect 'strictly increasing' comment

Comment: @FShrike Cute answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

We claim that $a:=\sup A=1. $ Assume by contradiction that $a<1.$  We have $f(a)>a. $ Therefore $f(a)>1,$ as otherwise $f(a)\in A.$ Hence $f(1)\ge f(a)>1.$

The argument $1$ may be replaced by $0<u<1.$ It can be done by adjusting the proof or by change of variables as follows.
For a fixed $0<u<1,$ let $g(x)={1\over u}f(ux).$ Then $g(0)>0$ and  $g(x)\neq x$ iff $f(x)\neq x.$ By the first part we get $g(1)>1,$ hence $f(u)>u.$

Answer (score 0):

**Claim**: We have $A=[0,1]$.

**Proof**: Assume that $[0,1]\setminus A\neq\emptyset$ and let $x^*\in[0,1]\setminus A=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\le x\}$. Since we have $f(x)\neq x$, we have $f(x^*)<x^*$. Now, let $x^\circ=\inf\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)<x\}$. Notice that $x^\circ\ge f(0)>0$ since $f(x)\ge f(0)$. Assume that $f(x^\circ)>x^\circ$, take a sequence $x_n\searrow x^\circ$ with $f(x_n)<x_n$ and notice that we hence eventually have $f(x_n)<f(x^\circ)$, which is a contradiction to $f$ being non-decreasing. So, we have $f(x^\circ)<x^\circ$. But for all $x<x^\circ$ we have $f(x)>x$, so for $x<x^\circ$ sufficiently close to $x^\circ$ we have $f(x)>f(x^\circ)$, which is a contradiction again. This shows that $A=[0,1]$.

In particular, we have $\sup A\in A$ and $f(1)>1$.